# How to compute log of multvariate gaussian in matlab

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I am trying to compute `log(N(x | mu, sigma))` in MATLAB where

x is the data vector(Dimensions D x 1) , mu(Dimensions D x 1) is mean and sigma(Dimensions D x D) is covariance.

My present implementation is

```
function [loggaussian] = logmvnpdf(x,mu,Sigma)

 [D,~] = size(x);
 const = -0.5 * D * log(2*pi);

 term1 = -0.5 * ((x - mu)' * (inv(Sigma) * (x - mu)));
 term2 = - 0.5 * logdet(Sigma);    
 loggaussian = const + term1 + term2;
end

function y = logdet(A)
 y = log(det(A));
end
```

For some cases I get an error

```
Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =
NaN
```

I know you will point out that my data is not consistent, but I need to implement the function so that I can get the best approximate instead of throwing an warning. . How do I ensure that I always get a value.

Answer (score 1):

I think the warning comes from using `inv(Sigma)`. According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html), you should avoid using `inv` where its use can be replaced by `\` ([`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html)). This will give you both better speed and accuracy.

For your code, instead of `inv(Sigma) * (x - mu)` use `Sigma \ (x - mu)`.

Comment: Tried that too, even for that I get the exact same warning

Comment: Your matrix might indeed be [badly conditioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices). Can you post the values of `Sigma`?

Comment: Yes my matrix is indeed badly conditioned. Now I corrected it and fixed the error, so I dont have the matrix anymore. But what I want is the function to return some value say populated with all 0's or all inf's or whatever, instead of throwing an error

Comment: You can compute [`rcond`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rcond.html) yourself and return something else if it is near zero or `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

The following approach should be (a little) less sensitive to ill-conditioning of the covariance matrix:

```
function logpdf = logmvnpdf (x, mu, K)

n = length (x);

R = chol (K);

const = 0.5 * n * log (2 * pi);
term1 = 0.5 * sum (((R') \ (x  - mu)) .^ 2);
term2 = sum (log (diag (R)));

logpdf = - (const + term1 + term2);

end
```

If `K` is singular or near-singular, you can still have warnings (or errors) when calling `chol`.